# Javascript function to count button click?

Tags: javascript, button, count, reload

I have JavaScript code to count button clicks. But the counter is set to zero upon reloading the page.

Is there any solution to count button clicks, and also persist that variable value upon page reload?

```js
var count = 0;
var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");
// Line commented out as SO does not allow it
// window.localStorage.setItem("on_load_counter", count);
button.onclick = function() {
  count++;
  display.innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Count" id="countButton" />
<p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>
```

Comment: Use [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Comment: you can save the counter in cookies or in HTML5 storage\

Comment: Utilize session storage or local storage for that Satpal is right

Comment: Guys, he just have a little error in his code `var count = 0;` here

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable `localStorage.clickcount` that you can increment with every click.

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbpun21b/3/)